# pgadmin 4 import/export table does not work

Tags: csv, import, import-from-csv, pgadmin-4

I have made sure that the columns match the 'column to export' field in the columns tab, not null columns have data, tried in both csv and txt but all i get is a message saying:

> import/export job created

Nothing else: no errors, no warning, no completion.

windows 7 os
Version1.4
CopyrightCopyright 2013 - 2017, The pgAdmin Development Team
Python Version2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Flask Version0.11.1
Application ModeDesktop

till then ill try via psql

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but are you trying this as a superuser? I'm having the same issue and so trying to write it as a COPY statement, but get this response:

```
ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
SQL state: 42501
Hint: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

I'm not sure, but maybe the functionality in pgAdmin just constructs a COPY statement, then isn't properly relaying the error message back to you when it fails.

Sounds like psql is the right way to go, though.

Comment: yea i am a superuser,sorry for taking so long but i got that solved by still using pgadmin III instead of 4

Comment: Hi @Blue. I'm having the same issues. Did you find any other solutions, except for using version 3 or `psql`?

Comment: Same issue - importing works with psql and pgadmin3, but not on pgadmin4 where it just says the job was created

Comment: @trench i just upgraded to version 4 on pgadmin